# How to make button class "pull-right" only on larger devices and "center-block" only on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

`class="btn btn-buy pull-right addToCart"`

this is my code, i want pull-right only on larger devices and center-block on small devices, how to make it? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Try `<div class="float-xl-right">Float right on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider</div>` for the float right

Answer (score 0):

instead of using float

try these class of flex ,it's more convenience 
class="d-flex justify-content-xl-end justify-content-md-center"

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way. change `float-lg-right` as you need for large screen.

```
<div class="float-lg-right text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom class and add a css media query for it targetting lager devices, and set the default value smaller devices, refer below

```
<a class="btn btn-buy addToCart toggleRight">Button</a>
<style>
 .toggleRight{
        text-align:center;
        float:none;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .toggleRight{
        float:right;
        text-align:initial;
    }
    }
</style>
```